# Open Source Turn-Based Strategy Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine

Is anyone aware of a turn-based based strategy game engine that is open source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of open source turn based strategy games located [here](http://rubyforge.org/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=83) 
They are all written in Ruby and some use rails.

Answer (score 2):

[FreeCiv](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) is FOSS. I don't know what engine it uses, or whether it is usable outside the game, but since it's open-source, you can always have a look inside.

Comment: Not exactly a game "engine" as such, but this was my first through as well. Also the [Battle for Wesnoth][1]. 

   [1] http://www.wesnoth.org/

Answer (score 2):

[Xconq](http://xconq.sourceforge.net/) is another option.